# How do you set --author and --message for the image using buildah?

Tags: podman, buildah

There is both a `buildah commit` and a `podman commit` however the `buildah commit` doesn't support `--author` or `--message` which is provided by `podman`. Is there a way to get this functionality with just `buildah`? Or do I need to take a container online with the image merely to set the author and message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an image’s author with [`buildah config --author`](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/main/docs/buildah-config.md).

As far as I can tell there’s no `buildah` equivalent to `podman commit --message`.

Answer (score 1):

`buildah config --comment` is the equivalent of `podman commit --message`.